# KVM Machine Webhosting

Tags: linux, kvm, webserver

On My Host CentOS 7 Linux I'm having guest system as Windows 2008 Server.

I'm having 2 website configured on IIS Webserver of Windows 2008, but how do I connect the webserver from internet. There is only one public IP, and one TP link router.

let me know if you need any more information.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to use 'bridged networking' in your VM so that you will get a  private IP from your router then you can use the [virtual server](http://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-1106.html) feature in TP-Link router to bind port 80 of your VM with port 80 of your public IP

Comment: I tried doing it but can't find any bridge connection in KVM.

Comment: You can add it from "configure network interface" window see this tutorial http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/configure-bridged-networking-for-kvm-on-ubuntu-14-10.html

Comment: Do you mean I need to create a br0 in the host centos 7 machine. If yes then which IP do I need to provide it.